# Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content'). activity_main.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to the forum and just started learning about Android app development. I was going through the tutorials at developer.android.com and already ran into an compiling error. I see these three errors on my activity_main.xml:

```
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').  activity_main.xml   
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'wrap content').   activity_main.xml   
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').  activity_main.xml
```

and here is my activity_main.xml code as of now:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap content"
        android:layout_height="wrap content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it throwing an error because wrap_content is an incorrect syntax or does it need to be declared elsewhere? Any help will be appreciated on how to troubleshoot or fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: wrap_content instead of wrap content

Comment: I am having the same error but my value is wrap_content. Everything seems to be on the proper syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just started learning myself.  I believe the problem is missing underscores.  It should read "wrap_content" not "wrap content".

Comment: I got this error too, by my mistake is "wrap_content ", an extra space in last of the string make everything wrong :D, stupid Android Studio, why can't it auto fix it :))

Answer (score 2):

It's `wrap_content` not `wrap content` . Change it and your problem should be long gone!

Answer (score 1):

it **must be** `wrap_content` **instead of** `wrap content`

**Change**

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap content"
        android:layout_height="wrap content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

**To**

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error while evaluating Xamarin on Mac. It was an issue with target framework. My guess is that certain earlier versions of Android did not support all values in this Xml tag, or Xamarin could not handle it properly, or something like that. I changed Options->Build->General->Target framework from
Android 2.1 to Android 2.2, and the build was successful after that.

Answer (score 0):

I was typing in "warp_content" and it was messing up for me lol. It's "wrap_content" not "warp_content"